# Pretty way to use enumarators

Tags: c++, c++11, enums, type-conversion

In my code I need to use enumarators to make sure that only a set of values could be assigned to certain instances however, I am tired of making conversions from `int` to `enum` types and vice versa. Is there something like `int enum` to avoid those ugly looking `static_cast`s?

Comment: Well, there's `+` for one direction.

Comment: Are you using `enum class` or simple `enum`?

Comment: @RSahu: I use `enum class` because I have more than one `enum class`es and they have members with the same names.

Comment: Is use of `std::integral_constant` instead of `enum`s an option for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to allow implicit conversions between enumerators and variables of the underlying type don't use C++11's scoped enumerations.

```
enum class scoped : unsigned
{
    Enumerator_1,
};

enum /*class*/ unscoped : unsigned
{
    Enumerator_1,
};

int main()
{
    unsigned a = static_cast<unsigned>(scoped::Enumerator_1); // explicit conv
    unsigned b = unscoped::Enumerator_1;                      // implicit conv allowed
}
```

Specifically, don't use `enum class` (or `enum struct`). You're still allowed to specify an underlying type, but implicit conversions are now allowed.

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b1fbdcd0ed1fb8f6)